# RabbitMQ sending message in transaction

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Is it possible to run below code in a transaction so if an exception is thrown in the business processing we can roll back the message we sent to the queue?

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("queue1", data);

//do some processing

rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("queue2", data);
```

Need for this is what if something went wrong after sending message to queue1, but we're not able to send message to queue2. Or what if issue network or some other issue in sending message to queue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this code is running on a listener container thread (`onMessage()` or `@RabbitListener`) and the container and template both have `setChannelTransacted(true)` then the publishing (and delivery) will run in the same transaction; throwing an exception will cause everything to be rolled-back.

If this is in some arbitrary java class (not running on a container thread), then you need to start the transaction before the method runs...

```
    @Transactional
    public void send(String in) {
        this.template.convertAndSend("foo", in);
        if (in.equals("foo")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
        this.template.convertAndSend("bar", in);
    }
```

Here's a full Spring Boot application that demonstrates the feature...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So40749877Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40749877Application.class, args);
        Foo foo = context.getBean(Foo.class);
        try {
            foo.send("foo");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        foo.send("bar");
        RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        // should not get any foos...
        System.out.println(template.receiveAndConvert("foo", 10_000));
        System.out.println(template.receiveAndConvert("bar", 10_000));
        // should be null
        System.out.println(template.receiveAndConvert("foo", 0));
        RabbitAdmin admin = context.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class);
        admin.deleteQueue("foo");
        admin.deleteQueue("bar");
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue foo() {
        return new Queue("foo");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue bar() {
        return new Queue("bar");
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo fooBean() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }

    public static class Foo {

        @Autowired
        private RabbitTemplate template;

        @Transactional
        public void send(String in) {
            this.template.convertAndSend("foo", in);
            if (in.equals("foo")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("test");
            }
            this.template.convertAndSend("bar", in);
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Transactions on the consumer side; this does not generally apply when using Spring because it manages the transaction, but when using the client directly...

```
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel(true);
channel.basicQos(1);
channel.txSelect();
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
channel.basicConsume("foo", new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, BasicProperties properties,
            byte[] body) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new String(body));

        getChannel().txRollback(); // delivery won't be requeued; remains unacked

        if (envelope.isRedeliver()) {
            getChannel().basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
            getChannel().txCommit(); // commit the ack so the message is removed
            getChannel().basicCancel(consumerTag);
            latch.countDown();
        }
        else { // first time, let's requeue
            getChannel().basicReject(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), true);
            getChannel().txCommit(); // commit the reject so the message will be requeued
        }
    }

});
latch.await();
channel.close();
connection.close();
```

Note the the `txRollback` does nothing in this case; only the ack (or reject) are transactional.

Comment: Thansk Gary , I did same thing but missed @EnableTransactionManagement , its working now. Though in that method I am using amqpAdmin to declare queue (I have to do that I know its not good), right now its not going to rollback that, though its not biggie, is there way to rollback that too!

Comment: No; infrastructure changes do not participate in transactions - see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) for rabbitmq transaction semantics.

Comment: In that link can you elaborate this statement: "On the consuming side, the acknowledgements are transactional, not the consuming of the messages themselves. "

Comment: It doesn't generally apply when using Spring because it manages the transaction. Hopefully my edit above explains the semantics of transactions on the consumer side.

Comment: Gary, if we slightly modify above send method with additional call of db and we want to do something like two phase commit using atomikas , I tried but ran into issue of atomikas config. Expecting spring boot to all automagically. So like  @Transactional
    public void send(String in) {
        this.template.convertAndSend("foo", in); jdbc.save(entity);
        if (in.equals("foo")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        }
        
    }

Comment: You should ask a new question not hijack an existing one; also code in comments is virtually unreadable. RabbitMQ doesn't support 2 phase commit.